# Is there a way to write a dataframe starting from a specific cell in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, dataframe, export

I am trying to write a DataFrame into an existing Excel sheet, which will use my imported data to do some operations. I tried to use the openpyxl library and the dataframe_to_rows function to do it.

It did actually write the dataframe in the good sheet but it didn't write it from the beginning of the cells (The excels functions request the data starting from a specific cell)

Here is my code :

```
sheet_name = ['Zones','Bilan','CTA', "Annuel", "Ventilation"] # The names of the differents sheet where i need to import my DataFrames 
vect_Data =  [Data1,Data2,Data3, sortie_annuel, Ventil_data] # The DataFrames i need to import in the sheets

wb = op.load_workbook(filename = nom_excel) # I imported openpyxl as op 
for i in range(len(sheet_name)):
    ws = wb[sheet_name[i]]
    for cells in ws :
        for cell in cells : 
            cell.value = None
    for r in dataframe_to_rows(vect_Data[i] , index=False , header=True): 
        ws.append(r)
        
wb.save(filename = nom_excel)
```

Is there a way to force the dataframe_to_rows function to begin from a specific cell?

Thank you for your answers.